# AWS Bucket redirect non html files

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, bucket

Based on [AWS Redirect documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html), it's supposed to redirect from an object to another by adding the metadata tag : **Website-Redirect-Location**.

But I search around and didn't found any information, to know if this redirect only working for html files. Im wondering if I could redirect link from binary file. I have an old .msi file that need to be change by a .exe, but I want to redirect the .msi bucket link to download the new .exe.

Is there any limitation of redirect, or a specific option to add to make it work ?

**NOTE:** I put the .msi and .exe in the same bucket, both have public link to download them, I can access them without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem.

As exposed on [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff), REST API and Website endpoint are not supporting the same functionalities.

Also, see the following [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740084/amazon-s3-redirect-and-cloudfront) from where I got the first information in-between difference, this answer also provide more information how its work

And finally, I implemented [such as thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839125/get-amazon-s3-to-redirect-to-my-endpoint-on-missing-object-requests) on my Website endpoints to redirect to my .exe when requesting the .msi or any other missing files.